# ¿Como se ordena por el método de inserción en memoria dinamica( lista enlazada)?

Tags: c++

Hola me podrían dar ejemplos de como se ordena utilizando el método de inserción en una lista enlazada.
Esto me lo pide el ejercicio que estoy realizando: 
Debe ordenar el registro de la muestra por tipo de producto

```
#define LD "Leche Descremada"
#define LE "Leche Entera"
#define YG "Yogurt"
#define HL "Helado"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada debemos ver como crear una lista enlazada, como en tu código no viene, daré una breve explicación. Una lista enlazada son conjuntos de `nodos` los cuales se relacionan por medio de `punteros`, existen varios tipos de listas enlazadas, `simples`, `dobles`, `circulares simples` y `circulares dobles` por poner un ejemplo.

[image: Lista simplemente enlazada]

Este es un claro ejemplo de una `lista enlazada simple`, como puedes observar contiene un contenedor para datos y un `apuntador` el cual apunta a otro nodo de nuestra lista, también tenemos un `apuntador` `inicio` y `fin`, los cuales nos ayudan a volver al inicio de la lista o a determinar si llegamos al final de la misma.

Codigo para crear una lista simple con inserción.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//Aqui se crea la estructura de la lista
//Y puedes observar que dentro contiene un dato de su mismo tipo llamado sig
//ese sera el apuntador a otros nodos.
struct nodo{
    int x;
    struct nodo *sig;
};
typedef nodo *nueva;

//Definimos el inicio de la lista y el fin como nulos.
nueva primero=NULL;
nueva ultimo=NULL;

void agregar_insercion(nodo *lista){
    lista->sig = NULL;
    //Caso especial si la lista esta vacía
    //Apuntaremos al nodo como primero y ultimo elemento.
    if(primero==NULL){
        primero=lista;
        ultimo=lista;
    }
    //Si la lista no esta vacía, tendremos 3 casos diferentes.
    else{
        //Caso uno, el nodo debe ir al inicio de la lista.
        //Haremos que primero ahora apunte al nuevo nodo.
        if(lista->x <= primero->x){
            lista->sig=primero;
            primero=lista;
        }
        //Caso dos, el nodo debe ir al final de la lista.
        //Por lo cual ultimo sera el nodo que estamos insertando.
        else if(lista->x >= ultimo->x){
            ultimo->sig = lista;
            ultimo=lista;
        }
        // El ultimo caso es que tengamos que insertar en un elemento intermedio
        // Por lo cual usaremos un nodo auxiliar para recorrer la lista y encontrar la posicione a insertar.
        else{
            nueva aux=primero;
            while(lista->x > aux->sig->x){
                aux = aux->sig;
            }
            lista->sig = aux->sig;
            aux->sig=lista;
        }
    }
}

//Una función para mostrar la lista.
void mostrar(){
    nueva aux = primero;
    while(aux != NULL){
        cout<< aux->x <<endl;
        aux = aux->sig;
    }
}

//Funcion main.
int main(){
    int x;
    //Un for de 5 donde vamos a añadir valores a la lista
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        nueva nuevo1=(nueva)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
        cout<<"ingrese valor a agregar : ";
        cin>>x;
        nuevo1->x = x;
        agregar_insercion(nuevo1);
    }
    ultimo->sig=NULL;
    mostrar();
}
```

Espero el codigo te pueda ayudar saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya pongo en practica lo aprendido :)